# Javascript and Hoisting

Tags: javascript

In my code, the x value is undefined. If I remove `if` block, the x value is displayed as 77. I don't understand why `if` block is modifying the x value.

```js
var x = 77;

function fn() {
  if (false) {
    var x = 55;
  }
  console.log(x);
}

fn();
```

Comment: By using the `var` keyword, you have made this a _local_ variable inside the scope of the function. _Because_ of hoisting, that variable _exists_, but because the if condition is not true, it did _not_ get a value assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var x = 77;

function fn() {
  if (false) {
   var x = 55;
  }
  console.log(x); // undefind
}

fn();
```

In the intermediate phase, `x` will be hoisted to its scope:

```
    var x = 77;
    function fn() {
    //var x = undefind; intermediate phase
      if (false) {
        var x = 55;
      }
      console.log(x);
    }

    fn();
```

```js
var x = 77;

function fn() {
  if (false) {
    x = 55;
  }
  console.log(x); // 77
}

fn();
```

Answer (score 2):

The x variable is redeclared and hoisted inside the function, but never set because `if (false)` will never be reached thus `undefined`. The outer x is known inside the function if you remove the inner declaration.

This can be solved by using `const` or `let` (ES6) instead of `var`. `const` and `let` is not hoisted and lives only inside of the brackets they are declared:

```
const x = 77;

function fn() {
  if (false) {
    const x = 55;
  }
  console.log(x);  // 77
}
fn()
```

Another solution is to just use two different variable names or remove the var inside the if statement depending on your needs...

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `var` inside the if-statement. That will fix the hoisting issue.

```
var x = 77;

function fn() {
    if(false) {
        x = 55;
    }
    console.log(x); // 77
}

fn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the scope of the function, the variable x is hoisted to the top as follows `var x;` If you print it, you get `undefined`. It is never assigned a variable as it is not going inside the if block

Answer (score 0):

You can also use let keyword.

```
let x = 77;

function fn() {
  if (false) {
    let x = 55;
  }
  console.log(x); // 77
}

fn()
```

Answer (score 0):

one should use wither ES6 define syntax const OR let while assigning the variable, if needs to mutate the variable then use let, otherwise use const , stop using var .
In your scenario while using var there, it means you are trying to re initialize the x, it gets hoisted 
var x = 77; means
var x; outside the block.
So one should not need to re initialize the x just pass the value or either use let or const .

```
function fn() {
  if (false) {
  // 
    x = 55;
  }
  console.log(x);
}

fn();
```